# attach one row to a cell's location

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking to SORT an `IMPORTRANGE()` into a spreadsheet and have the cells that aren't imported into the spreadsheet follow along with the imported range. Each cell in one of the imported columns has a unique address.
For example, I am importing information into columns `A:B`, and in column C, there is unique data that needs to follow along with the imported information in `A:B`  in cell `C:C`.
The difficult thing is that in the sheet I am importing from, cells are added weekly.

Is there a way to have the imported range always keep the same row data in it?
Hopefully my question makes sense

I have tried:
=arrayformula(VLOOKUP(A2:A,QUERY('UNIQUE IDS'!A:C,"select A, B"),{1,2},FALSE)) - this bases what I need to find based on a stationary set of IDs. The problem with this is that it doesn't update the set of IDs that the formula is pulling from, so I would need to update the stationary set of IDs frequently

`=sort(filter(query('UNIQUE IDS'!A:C,"select A, B"),query('UNIQUE IDS'!A:C,"select B")="ACTIVE"),1,FALSE)`
I have also tried this, this doesn't link together the rows **at all** however, it does give me the option to sort the values how I want them.

I have outlined this in a [google sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bcl0qt2zd0vPXL7Wxv8PrZitYYa27VPBybrRVvDgLV0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you provide an example of what would be the outcome that you are looking for?

Comment: @GabrielCarballo for sure, does this loom work?: https://www.loom.com/share/31e018f8f31a4d849e8e8d6497e09400

Let's say we have column A w/ imported data in it, if I `SORT(QUERY()` , any information in every other column will stay stagnant right?
How do I get every other column's data to stick with the row's unique ID no matter how I SORT(QUERY() at any time. If I change the sort, order to descending from ascending, is there a way for all the other information not in ColA to come with the sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let's say you have 2 set of data sharing the same column-1 which is data "A",
and have a different column-2, which is data "B" and "C".

No matter the data is a range, a query, a filter, or whatever, they are all arrays.
As long as you work with the data as an array, you can do anything.

In this example...

1. we use `LAMBDA()` to name the 2 data set as `DATA_1` and `DATA_2`,
2. than use `QUERY()` to get rid of the extra blanks in `DATA_1`,
3. use `BYROW()` to iterate `DATA_1` and lookup matches data in column-1 and return column-2 of `DATA_2` as result,
4. use `LAMBDA()` to name the lookup result `LOOKUP`,
5. use `{}` to concat the two array side by side and form the output data.

with this formula, no matter how you re-arrange the source data, the result will always match themselves according to the value of column-1 (data "A"), and you can sort the output by column-1 at any given moment if you want to.

Comment: Perfect! Wow! Very Very helpful Ping, thank you!
I added the answer to the spreadsheet for everyone's reference.