# Can importrange keep keep all rows in the sheet together

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-formula

I'm using a combination of importrange and query functions to extract specific data from local spreadsheets and bring it into my master spreadsheet. The extracted data occupies rows A:K, while I use row L to write notes related to the information in that row. These notes are specific to each row.

However, the problem is that as I add more data from local sheets, the master sheet expands, causing the notes in column L to get detached from their corresponding rows. I'm wondering if there's a way to link the rows together so that the notes remain associated with the specific row they were intended for, even as more data is imported.

I know this has been asked before in places in the past like: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/22383612/importrange-function-a-way-to-keep-specific-rows-together?hl=en
just wondering if anything has changed?
Or is there a different program, app, extension, script, that I can use to accomplish this?

I've tried the following:
[attach one row to a cell's location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74706681/attach-one-row-to-a-cells-location)
also
something like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D1:D,QUERY(range,"select Col1,Col3,Col6",1) ,{1,2,3},FALSE)))
```

but that still requires you to update column D:D with the associated values...

Comment: Unfortunately not, what you can try is Filter Views. If you have that Master Sheet, and if you can hardcode the ranges of the local sheets imported in the QUERY maybe you MAY be to create a Filter View that emulates the conditions of your QUERY and allows you to link them.

Comment: Thanks Martin, just making sure there isn't anything I am missing. I know there are a lot of extensions nowadays that have a lot of possibilities.

Comment: @BenCamp Here's an [odd approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75613711/5479575) which you can give a shot at  for linking importrange dynamic data to static comments column or so...

Comment: Thanks for the input, I believe I've used that formula before hah, just didn't see a use for it in this context, thanks.